# accessing parts of an object

Tags: r

I have this:

```
> str(pa1)
 num [1:83, 1:9] -1.46 -2.28 -3.69 -4.98 -5 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:83] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:9] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
```

How do I access the last part of `pa1`shown above, that is

```
"PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a specific function for `dimnames`, and in general you get attributes with the `attr` function (as the output of `str` indicates).

```
dimnames(pa1)[[2]]
#or
attr(pa1,"dimnames")[[2]]
```